# Telerik alternative

Tags: telerik, third-party-software

When acquiring a greater software license our company must present at least two alternatives to the software we want to buy.

We want to use Telerik for extended editor functionality and image handling, are there any alternatives to this that we can compare Telerik with?

Comment: Well does keeping the out of the box one count? :-)

Comment: Not when in comes to acquiring new software, I'm afraid :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking Syncfusion, Dev express

Comment: Nice, thanks. I have also found Infrasistics, Obout and Innova Studios, but how related those are I don't know